# JSON data to a Spring MVC controller - error 415

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a problem with my application. When I send JSON data I get return error 415 - The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.
I am new in this and I still trying understanding this.

JSP page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form-temp").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        searchViaAjax();
    });
});

function searchViaAjax() {

    var temp = {}
    temp["temp"] = $("#temp").val();

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : "/update",
        data : JSON.stringify(temp),
        dataType : 'json',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 600000,
        success : function(temp) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
            //display(temp);
        }
    });

}

/* function display(temp) {
    var json = "<h4>Ajax Response</h4><pre>"+ JSON.stringify(data, null, 4) + "</pre>";
    $('#feedback').html(json);
} */
</script> 

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Formularz wprowadzania temperatury</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form" method="post" action="update" id="form-temp">
        <div><label for="temp">Podaj temperaturę</label></div>
        <div><input type="text" name="temp" id="temp"/></div>
        <div><button id="sendBtn">Dodaj</button></div>
    </form>

    <form id="form" method="get" action="stats">
        <div><button id="sendBtn">Lista temperatur</button></div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import pl.e.rekrutacja.domain.repository.TempRepository;
import pl.e.rekrutacja.model.Temp;

@RestController
public class UpdateController {

    @Autowired
    private TempRepository tempRepository;

//  @ResponseBody

    @RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public String startPage(@RequestBody Temp temp){
        tempRepository.addTemp(temp);
        return "input_form_temp";
    }

}
```

Model class:

```
public class Temp {

    private double value;

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Temp(double value) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Application context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true"/> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="pl.e.rekrutacja" />
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id= "tempRepositoryImpl" class="pl.e.rekrutacja.domain.repository.impl.TempRepositoryImpl"/>  
</beans>
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                                 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

        <filter>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/webcontext/DispatcherServlet-context.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Try to add default constructor Temp() to let JSOn deserializer instantiate the class.

Comment: add to your controller @ResponseBody and return the updated Temp object

Comment: @StanislavL Your solution is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is returning a view name to the requested resource. Instead it must return the state of the Temp object in JSON format.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Temp tempStartPage(@PathVariable(@RequestBody Temp temp)) {

return tempRepository.addTemp(temp);
}
```

The `@ResponseBody` will handle the `consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json"` .

Comment: Your code is correct? Because I have error in Eclipse when I paste it.

Comment: OK, but I still have error.
Underline is Temp.
"Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
 - Syntax error, insert "Type VariableDeclaratorId" to complete 
  FormalParameter
 - Syntax error on token "Temp", ( expected"